# rails ams, Nested models undefined method `' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, nested-attributes, active-model-serializers

I have the following models:

```
class Appeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :applicant, :autosave => true
  belongs_to :appealer, :autosave => true
end

class Appealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appeals, :autosave => true
end

class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appeals
end
```

What I want is for every appealer to hold a reference to the applicant of his *last* appeal

so I modified Appealer model to:

```
class Appealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appeals, :autosave => true

  def last_applicant
    return self.appeals.last.applicant
  end
end
```

but I get the error:

```
undefined method `applicant' for nil:NilClass
```

what is strange that if I debug this (via RubyMine - Evaluate Expression) I can get the applicant.

If I try to get the last appeal:

```
class Appealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appeals, :autosave => true

  def last_appeal
    return self.appeals.last
  end
end
```

everything works.

Im working with active-model-serializer, tried to do it also in the serializer (I actually need this value on a specific call - not allover the model) but it also didnt worked with the same errors.

the AMS code:

```
class AppealerTableSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :appealer_id, :first_name, :last_name, :city
  has_many :appeals, serializer: AppealMiniSerializer

  def city
    object.appeals.last.appealer.city
  end

end
```

**MY QUESTION:**
How can I get the nested object attributes in my JSON?
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
My controller call:

```
class AppealersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    appealers = Appealer.all
    render json: appealers, each_serializer: AppealerTableSerializer, include: 'appeal,applicant'
  end
end
```

I've tried with and without the include, still not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, because this looks like you have Appealer record that doesn't have any appeals yet.

In such case, this code

```
def last_appeal
  return self.appeals.last
end
```

Will return nil, which won't raise any errors. But if you call this

```
def last_applicant
  return self.appeals.last.applicant
end
```

`return self.appeals.last` is nil and you try to call `applicant` method on nil object instead of Appeal object.

To fix it just add check for nil

```
class Appealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appeals, :autosave => true

  def last_applicant
    last = self.appeals.last

    if last.nil?
      return nil
    else
      return last.applicant
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: its not empty, as I wrote in my question, I can see the value in the debugger in Evaluate Expression

Comment: @yossico Can you post code that is calling serialization method?

Comment: I've added the controller call

Comment: You where right - it was a stupid nil check missing, I want to punch myself in the face