# rails save nested attributes in many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 5.

Here is my db structure

```
create_table :apps do |t|
  t.text :tech_assist_info
  t.integer :scheduled
  t.integer :status
  t.text :notes
  t.belongs_to :operator, index: true, foreign_key: true
end

create_table :boards do |t|
  t.string :board_type
  t.string :registration_mark
  t.belongs_to :app, index: true, foreign_key: true
end

create_table :app_files do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.integer :file_type
  t.belongs_to :app, index: true, foreign_key: true
end

create_table :board_files do |t|
  t.belongs_to :app_file, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.belongs_to :board, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

and here is the model files

```
# app.rb
class App < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :operator

  has_many :app_files
  has_many :boards

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :boards, :app_files, allow_destroy: true
end


#board.rb
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app
  has_many :board_files
  has_many :app_files, through: :board_files

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :board_files, :app_files
end

#board_file.rb
class BoardFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board
  belongs_to :app_file
end


#app_file.rb
class AppFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app
  has_many :board_files
  has_many :boards, through: :board_files
end
```

---

Question the following

How can I do the save/create functionality of nested objects?

I am trying this but that don't work.
I looked in the documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

```
@app = App.new({
   tech_assist_info: "abc", status: 1, boards_attributes: [
           {board_type: "ABC55", registration_mark: "qwerty", app_files_attributes: [
           {name: "name.pdf", file_type: 5}]}
   ]
})

@app.save
```

Thanks

Comment: can this help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150731/rails-ams-nested-models-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass   ?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve it in any form or rails console? What is the error you see? The errors will be raise if you use `@app.save!`

Comment: Yea, I got the following message
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Boards app files app must exist